# create a web site using Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.Sites.Add

Tags: iis-7, installation

I want to create a web site in my setup project using `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.Sites.Add` method, but it needs a physical path of the web site to be specified. I want the web site to be created at it's default location. How can I find out the physical path of the default location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when adding a new site this would have a different directory to any pre-existing site.  For example IIS comes preconfigured with "Default Web Site" site and the physical path for this typically points to:

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
```

You would not normally create a second site that also points to that directory.  As an example you might configure the second site to point to (or any other preferred location):

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot_secondsite\
```

That said, if you really want to have multiple sites with the same physical path then you should be able to use [`Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.Sites`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.sites%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property to enumerate all current sites and from there extract the physical path.